# Debugging Webkit in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, webkit

I am able to build webkit on windows7 under Visual Studio 2008..But for the purpose of debugging when I am putting breakpoints in source code, any of the breakpoints are not hitting. I am able to download symbols for every module required for the project. After running the project it is just launching the Safari without firing the breakpoints. Does anybody have any ideas about it or some links to refer regrading debugging webkit with visual Studio debugger. I have already looked the information provided on WebKit website and followed all steps but still unable to debug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebKit has started using a multiprocess architecture (WebKit2) a while ago, so you should attach to the WebKit2WebProcess process after launching Safari (see http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Debugging%20the%20WebKit2%20Web%20Process#UsingVisualStudio2005onWindows: for the reference).

Comment: Yes, When Safari Lunches, attach process window is also showing WebKit2webProcess, and I also tried to attach with this process, still none of the breakpoints are firing..One more question I installed Safari 5.1 version, in which Debug menu is visible but "Use WebKit2 for New Tabs" option is not available in this menu..

Comment: Does your breakpoint stay enabled after you launch Safari? I believe you use Tools/Scripts/debug-safari --debug to start debugging?

Comment: Yes, they remained enable..and I built it with Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug and when it did not work. I build the project from visual studio itself..

Comment: Hmm... Did you try Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug to that end? I have never managed to correctly build WebKit using MSVS.

Comment: So now r u able to guess what I am missing..:P

Comment: Not really. So, you built using build-webkit, started MSVS using debug-safari, launched with F5 and attached to the WebKit2WebProcess, to no avail? Could there be several WebKit2WebProcesses?

Comment: No..After building the webkit from Tools\Script\build-webkit --debug, I followed the steps on "www.webkit.org/building/debug.html". And after pressing the F5 when safari starts to run, I opened the process window and there I attached "WebKit2webProcess"..

Comment: Here's a plugin for VS for debugging multiprocess applications: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GreggMiskelly.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool